# Guardar valores de query LINQ en clase Modelo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Tengo la siguiente consulta de la cual quiero guardar sus valores en una clase modelo y retornar los resultados, pero no tengo idea de como, aquí mi código.
(Es un método de un servicio svc)

```html
 public interface MyInterface
 {
   [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetAllData/{idUser}/{Tipo}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   List<MyModel> GetAllData(string idUser, string Tipo);
   }
```

```html
public List<MyModel> GetAllData(string idUser, string Tipo)
{
  using (MyEntities bd = new MyEntities ())
  {
  if (idUser != null && Tipo!=null)
  {
  short iduser = Convert.ToInt16(idUser);
 
  if (Tipo == "P")
  {                        
  var query = (from m in bd.tabla1
  join C in bd.tabla2 on m.codigo equals C.codigo         
  where m.campo == C.campo && C.IdUser == iduser
  select new {
  //aqui lo que necesito es guardar los resultados de la query en los campos de mi modelo                                             
  }).ToList();
  
  return ... aqui debe retornar los resultados de lista;
  }
  else
  {
  return null;
  }
}
else
{
return null;
}
};
}
```

Modelo

```html
  public class MyModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public int Empresa { get; set; }

        public string Codigo { get; set; }

        public short Campo { get; set; }

        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: el formato para el select new es NombreCampo(este tu lo pones a tu gusto)=Valor(como se llame el campo en tu query). lo que devolverías al hacer eso sería un tipo object, tendrias que pasarlos a tu modelo antes de retornarlo.

Comment: y como los paso al modelo? @L.Ronquillo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = (from m in bd.tabla1
            join C in bd.tabla2 on m.codigo equals C.codigo         
            where m.campo == C.campo && C.IdUser == iduser    
            select new MyModel {
               Id = campoQueContieneElId,
               Nombre = campoQueContieneElNombre,
               // resto de propiedades                             
             }).ToList();

return query;
```

Answer (score 1):

Te muestro un codigo adaptado para que no tengas tanto if anidados

```
public List<MyModel> GetAllData(string idUser, string Tipo)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(idUser) 
        || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Tipo))
        return null;

    if (Tipo != "P")
        return null;

    using (MyEntities bd = new MyEntities())
    {
        short iduser = Convert.ToInt16(idUser);

        var query = (from m in bd.tabla1
                        join C in bd.tabla2 on m.codigo equals C.codigo         
                        where m.campo == C.campo && C.IdUser == iduser
                    select new {
                        Id = m.Id,
                        Nombre = m.Nombre,  
                        ...
                    }).ToList();

        return query;
    }
}
```

como veras puedes salir con un `return` sin tener que definir el `else` en todos los casos